# PowerBI trying to work out total order value based on product selection and then count number of orders by total size

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table of orders like the below

| Row | Order_ref | Product | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Socks | £5 |
| 2 | A | Shoes | £10 |
| 3 | B | Socks | £5 |
| 4 | B | Socks | £5 |
| 5 | C | Shoes | £10 |
| 6 | C | Socks | £5 |

I have a visual showing the total value of socks (£20) and shoes (£20) called visual one. I want to add another visual showing the unique count of orders over £10 that changes when the user selects the product.

This should show as 3 when no selection is made on visual one (as each of orders A, B and C is worth £10 or more) but should show as 1 when socks is selected (as only order B contains £10+ of socks) and 2 when shoes are selected (as orders A and C both contain £10 or more of shoes).

Ideally I'd like a solution that could be applied to any selection made from the data (my actual data table has many more columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this measure:

```
Total_Count = 
VAR Param_01 = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
    YourTable,YourTable[Order_ref],YourTable[Product]),
    "Total_Value",CALCULATE(SUM(YourTable[Value])))
RETURN
COUNTX(
FILTER(
Param_01,[Total_Value]>=10),[Total_Value])
```

If we test it out on a visual single card:

No Selection

[image: No_Selection]

Socks Selected:

[image: sd]

Shoes Selected:

[image: Sgh]

I hope It solves your problem :)

Comment: I have not created measures for various order size bands. By adding all of these measures to the y axis of a stacked column chart I can plot the total number of orders of different sizes and this changes as the user makes selections elsewhere on the dashboard.


However as each order size has a separate measure the chart is a stacked column chart. Is there a way to have a measure or calculated column that would allow the order sizes to be plotted side by side?

Answer (score 0):

> I have not created measures for various order size bands.

Good thing, because you don't create measures for bands, you create calculated columns, because you can't put a measure on an axis of a visual. (Try it).